# What type of hinge is this?

Tags: cabinets, hinges

I need to replace some bent (30 year old) hinges on our kitchen cabinets, but I don’t know what to search for. I have looked in the big box stores and haven’t seen any that resemble the kind I need. I’m hoping that I can order some online, I just don’t know what search terms to use.

To be clear, I'm *not* asking for a particular brand recommendation, I'm asking for the ***type*** or ***style*** of hinge. [image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: They look like Amerock hinges.

Comment: Product recommendations are off topic here, but I'm not going to vote to close unless others agree.  I'd browse the woodworking sites like Rockler and Woodworkers Supply, there is even a site called "HingeOutlet"   I'm sure you'll find what you are looking for.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson How is my question a request for a product recommendation?

Comment: @ARich It's borderline, that's why I didn't vote to close. Most questions here are "how to" but I respected your question enough not to vote to close.   Take care and sorry if I offended you.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson No offense taken. I wanted to understand why you thought my question was off topic; I edited my question to be a little more clear. Many questions on this site are not strictly "how to" questions, so I respectfully disagree that this question is borderline. :)

Comment: @ARich NP, good to have a civilized discussion with you on the internet, not much of that happening these days.  I respect your disagreement and have no issues with that.  We're fine!  Take Care and DIY on!

Comment: Look like a good quality stuff. May be better to fix it. The replacement, you will find, could be lower quality.

Comment: Take one off -- you might find it looks like one of these: https://www.thehardwarehut.com/cabinet_hinges-demountablehinges.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I was looking for. Shout-out to the comments and answers for pointing me in the right direction. The keywords I was missing are ***Self-Closing***, ***Double Demountable***, and ***Overlay***. My particular hinges are 1/2" (13mm).

[Hinge Outlet: Demountable Hinges](https://www.hingeoutlet.com/collections/demountable-hinges-single-and-double)

Answer (score 1):

I think that's a partial wrap overlay hinge.  Overlay means the door sits on the front of the faceframe when closed.  Partial wrap means the cabinet side of the hinge wraps along the edge of the faceframe where it is attached.  There are more components in the hinge though - maybe it's self-closing?

Comment: +1 for helping with the self-close search term!

Answer (score 1):

You will most likely not find an exact replacement for those hinges. The face frame and door looks like they even have cutouts to allow that hinge to fit and work the way it is intended. There are hinges that will work in its place, but the thing you do not have the info o is what the "overlay" is. This is the dimension that the door overlaps the frame of the cabinet. It can be 1/4", 3/8", 1/2" and 3/4". Some doors can have even larger overlay. Yours, just to guess, looks like it may be a 1/2" overlay. Here is a [link](https://www.google.com/search?q=surface%20mount%20cabinet%20hinges&tbm=isch&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CPQBEKzcAigAahcKEwj4qYn4ps3wAhUAAAAAHQAAAAAQCQ&biw=1903&bih=937#imgrc=yNCQttbX2MxXfM&imgdii=J_f9QH_5V6jz5M) to a hinge that will supposedly work in your case. It have more mounting holes and some are elongated. The extra mounting holes will get past the cutouts the original hinges have since if you tried to use a different hinge that had mounting screws in the same place the screws may not hold because of the cutouts that the original hinges used. The new hinges having screws in different places will allow the mounting screws to go into new wood.

Comment: +1 for the 1/2” overlay. As you can see in my answer, I *was* able to find hinges of the same style and size, so fortunately I won’t have to go down the route of finding a different style that would work!